# How to create IObservable from delegate?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

This code:

```
// NOTE: IQuote DOES NOT inherit from EventArgs
public interface IQuote// : EventArgs
{
}

class C
{
   //NOTE, this is NOT public event EventHandler<IQuote> QuoteChangeEvent;
    public delegate void QuoteChangeEvent(IQuote q);
}

var c = new C();

c.OnQuoteChange += ProcessQuoteChange;


public static void ProcessQuoteChange(IQuote q)
{
}
```

works fine. Now I want to use `Rx`. This doesn't work, i.e., it doesn't even compile:

```
var priceChangedObservable = Observable.FromEvent<QuoteChangeEvent, QuoteChangeEvent>(
    (handler) =>
    {
        QuoteChangeEvent quoteHandler = (e) => handler(e);                   
    },
    eh => c.OnQuoteChange += eh,
    eh => c.OnQuoteChange -= eh
    );
```

On the line `(handler) =>`

```
- "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   
   Error    CS1643  Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression  
   of type 'Func<Action<QuoteChangeEvent>,   
   QuoteChangeEvent>'       294 Active"
```

On the `handler(e)`

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'IQuote' to
>   'QuoteChangeEvent'        296 Active

What is the correct way to create an `IObservable` from a `delegate`?

Comment: What do you mean that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: @DavidG, I have no idea what the correct syntax is to create such an IObservable . There are several COMPILER errors on creating priceChangedObservable.

Comment: Then give us the errors!

Comment: @DavidG, See the edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Observable.FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>`, you should pass `<QuoteChangeEvent, IQuote>`:

```
var priceChangedObservable = Observable.FromEvent<QuoteChangeEvent, IQuote>(
    handler =>
    {
        QuoteChangeEvent quoteHandler = (e) => { handler(e); }; 
        return quoteHandler;         
    },
    eh => c.OnQuoteChange += eh,
    eh => c.OnQuoteChange -= eh
);
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I had a typo in parameter two as you point out.

Comment: It's a little neater if you go `handler => e => handler(e)`.